# Netbeans shows 'Bad value " " for attribute "id" on element "div". An ID must not contain whitespace' on <div id="${...}">

Tags: jsp, netbeans, el

I am trying to dynamically assign `<div id>` within `<c:forEach>` loop in JSP page. When I assign `id` using expression language like below,

```
<c:forEach ... varStatus="loop">
    <div id="${loop.index}">test</div>
</c:forEach>
```

I am getting this line of code underlined with error message.

> Bad value " " for attribute "id" on element "div". An ID must not contain whitespace.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the underlining just happening in you IDE? Or does the page genuinely not work?

Comment: I am using NetBeans 8.1 and page works itself., but id is not assinged...

Comment: So in other words `${loop.index}` is empty?

Comment: No! when i pass it to javascript as argument in onclick function it shows correct index!

Answer (score 1):

> *What am I doing wrong?*

Nothing related to the error message. It's a false negative and needs to be reported as a bug to the Netbeans team.

However, there is actually a technical problem with the given code snippet: HTML element IDs [may not](http://validator.w3.org) start with a number. There's also a design problem (not techncial) with given code snippet: relying on element IDs on multiple elements of the same type/nature is not abstract/reusable. Consider using a style class instead like as an `interface` in Java.